# Export number of groups from Gmail

Tags: gmail, export, gmail-contacts

I'm looking to export a number of groups at one time from Gmail, but don't see a way to do this.

I thought I might be able to create a group, and add all the groups I need to it, then export that, but I couldn't see how to do that either.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't nest groups of contacts in Gmail.

You can do what you want, but it will take a few more steps.

1. Create your "Export" group
2. Go to a group you want to export
3. Select all the contacts in that group
4. Add the selected contacts to your "Export" group
5. Repeat steps 2-4 until you've captured all the contacts you want to export
6. Export your contacts
7. Delete the "Export" group